# grab screenshot from second desktop

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, screenshot, desktop

I am using this code to grab screenshot in while loop:

```
filename = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('saved/'+filename+'.png')
```

Windows 10 is able to have more desktops, e.g. I have two desktops (under Task view icon / no two monitors, but two windows desktops with, this feature came win Win10). Now I want to run my program on second desktop and take screenshots from this second desktop each few seconds. But when I keep it running in second desktop and then I switch to first desktop (where I work usually), then just screenshots of first desktop are grabbed. How should I use it for my scenario?

Comment: Try using Desktopmagic instead. https://github.com/ludios/Desktopmagic/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thanks, but how to tell to Desktopmagic that I need desktop2? I am always getting desktop1

Comment: FYI I am not using two monitors, just 2 desktops in windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I created the [MSS](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/index.html) module specifically for that use:

```
# coding: utf-8
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

from mss import mss


with mss() as sct:
    while 'capturing':
        filename = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.png")
        sct.shot(mon=2, output=filename)
        sleep(1)
```

The monitor number is set in `sct.shot(mon=N, ...)` where `mon` is the monitor number as saw by the OS. It means that the monitor 2 can be the 1 for you, so just have a try and let me know you thoughts.

Comment: Hi Tiger-222, my problem is, that I do not have second monitor but second Desktop in Windows 10 (when you click on Task View icon, you can add New Desktop and place some programs there). So I want to grab and save screenshot from that desktop even when I am working in desktop1. Any idea how to do it there please?

Comment: Oh OK, it was not clear. I do not have an answer for that but will check if it can be done and added to MSS.